# How does one prevent existing text in uitextview from being overwritten

Tags: ios

I have included a UITextView in 1 screen of my beta app. It contains text "Test whether add text" when the screen is first opened. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXa4T.png)If user taps on the UITextView, all of the pre existing text - "Test whether add text" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Mlg.png)is selected such that if the user begins to enter new text using keyboard ( example; " why" ), the pre existing text  - "Test whether add text" is overwritten.

The user expects instead that typing while the pre existing text is selected, that newly entered text will be appended to the pre existing text ( "Test whether add text why"). With some experimentation I have found that if the pre existing text is selected and then uppercased(), then the newly entered text is appended with without overwriting "Test whether add text" with one caveat - the pre existing text is all uppercase. I am not enthused by the prospect of having the pre existing text change to uppercase and would like to avoid the side effect. I have tried building a simple test bed with a single ViewController and a UITextView and when I tap into the textview, it works just the way I want so I am even more puzzled.

In my viewdidload of my app's screen - "A Project" ( not the test bed ), I set the uitextview delegate to the "A Project" and the "A Project" view controller includes UITextVIewDelegate.

It seems that my inexperience with Xcode is blinding me to something that should be very obvious and appeal to someone to please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the following `UITextViewDelegate` method

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: textView.text.characters.count-1, length: 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed this solution BUT I did and you really helped. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding (: